# using CSS extend div heights of all divs in a row as content adds in one single row

Tags: css

I've 3 divs as columns in a single row using CSS float left attribute and I want to increase the heights of all the columns as content adds up in any column so that the height of all the 3 columns remains relative to the initial height.
How should I do that??
(I'm using 960 CSS grid)

Answer (score 0):

give the container a defined height (i think the classname is container_12 or container_16) and set the grid class you're using to height:100%;display:block;.

Comment: btw i mean the container that holds the three divs. i reckoned you had one.

Comment: if I set the height with a defined value, when the content extends to more than the defined height, the content is masked and not visible. The height may vary per page to page and so I need a flexible height, not a fix one... or am I missing something on what you are saying??

Comment: no this can be true. If you want to keep the heights equal you;ve to get a defined height, maybe if you loose the display:block; it will work.